Does Windows support arbitrary boot arguments?
On Linux, the kernel command line is used to both configure the kernel and configure userland processes. A process can run a startup, read /proc/cmdline, and decide what course of action to take based on its contents. Is there anything like this in Windows? I'm imagining that it would work by creating two or more boot menu entries in the BCD.

In theory yes, as Windows knows which BCD entry was used to start it and software could look up its parameters (the same way bcdedit maps it to the "{current}" alias), but 1) access to HKLM\BCD### requires Administrator privileges; 2) the 'elements' of each entry are identified by ID rather than string name, as well as being strongly-typed, so bcdedit can only be used to set those elements which it knows about, so the only place to put arbitrary data is the loadoptions element (which takes a string) – but there is practically no documentation on what syntax it uses.
As another option, Windows probably still has support for the "Hardware profiles" feature, which used to provide a way to switch between multiple HKLM\System\CurrentControlset\Hardware Profiles\####->Current registry keys, but the UI for configuring those was removed in ~2021 so it's reasonable to assume that this feature is not likely to function correctly even if you enable it in some other way.
So in practice I would go with 'no'.
